# iOS 7.1 update breaks External Accesory inputStream UART read ability

Tags: ios, ios7.1, external-accessory, mfi

We have MFI approved accessory device. Our protocol assumes continuous readings from accessory in UART mode. It was working perfect before iOS 7.1, but after testing on the iOS 7.1 it is not working properly.

In ATS test suite log we can see success eap records and some AccessoryDataTransfer acked by iPhone.

We can reproduce problem using EADemo. EADSessionController stops read data after some show/close cycles.

Only killing EADemo and relaunch allows us read some data.

**Configuration:**
iPhone 4 and newer (iOS 7.0), any iPod (iOS 6.x) - OK
iPhone 4s, iPhone 5 (iOS7.1) - Failed

**What happens with EA framework in iOS 7.1?**

Comment: Perhaps you need to raise an incident with Apple Developer Support?

Comment: Noticing similar behaviour with our iDynamo readers.

Comment: My company ran into the same issue and reported it to Apple. It has been confirmed as a bug but we do not have any ETA on when a fix will be provided. If you have received further information on this topic or found a workaround for this issue please post it.

Comment: @Vladimir Koltunov, @ chriswhite, Now we are facing same issue on iOS 7.1.Most of the time [[_session inputStream] hasBytesAvailable]; fails to read/receive data from accessory. Can you provide information how to solve this issue if it is already solved. Otherwise if it is an Apple issue where we can get evidence?. Please guide me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Apple confirmed - this is a bug. 7.1.1 update does not solved this issue. Solution is unavailable. Still waiting patch from Apple.

Comment: Apple support guy supposed to install iOS8 beta 2. iPhone 4s works good with UART accessories now.

Answer (score 1):

Apple just released update 7.1.2 claiming they solved the issue.

"• Fixes a bug with data transfer for some 3rd party accessories, including bar code scanners"*